# DNSPython: NoAnswer en MX y NS

Tags: python

Estoy leyendo el libro "Python para Pentesters" de Daniel Echeverri Montoya. Estando en la pagina 17 he intentado probar el código, sin embargo al intentar hacer la ejecución de la función `dns.resolver.query` con el parámetro de MX y NS me provoca un error de `NoAnswer`.

Aquí dejo el codigo:

```
import dns
import dns.resolver

pagina_web = "www.google.com"

ansMX = dns.resolver.query(pagina_web, 'MX')
ansNS = dns.resolver.query(pagina_web, 'NS')

print("\nImprimiendo ansMX:")
print("--------------------------------")
print(ansMX.response.to_text())

print("\nImprimiendo ansNS:")
print("--------------------------------")
print(ansNS.response.to_text())
```

Los dos errores son los siguientes:

- MX:

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/zorro/Desktop/Programas/Python/Pentester/Ejemplo 1/Ejemplo1.py", line 10, in <module>
      ansMX = dns.resolver.query(pagina_web, 'MX')
    File "C:\Users\zorro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\dnspython-1.15.0-py3.6.egg\dns\resolver.py", line 1132, in query
    File "C:\Users\zorro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\dnspython-1.15.0-py3.6.egg\dns\resolver.py", line 1053, in query
    File "C:\Users\zorro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\dnspython-1.15.0-py3.6.egg\dns\resolver.py", line 234, in __init__
  dns.resolver.NoAnswer: The DNS response does not contain an answer to the question: www.google.com. IN MX
  ```
- NS:

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/zorro/Desktop/Programas/Python/Pentester/Ejemplo 1/Ejemplo1.py", line 11, in <module>
      ansNS = dns.resolver.query(pagina_web, 'NS')
    File "C:\Users\zorro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\dnspython-1.15.0-py3.6.egg\dns\resolver.py", line 1132, in query
    File "C:\Users\zorro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\dnspython-1.15.0-py3.6.egg\dns\resolver.py", line 1053, in query
    File "C:\Users\zorro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\dnspython-1.15.0-py3.6.egg\dns\resolver.py", line 234, in __init__
  dns.resolver.NoAnswer: The DNS response does not contain an answer to the question: www.google.com. IN NS
  ```

Versiones de los programas que intervienen en el codigo:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Python 3.6
- DNSPython
- PyCharm Community 2017.2.4

Comment: Usa la versión non-www:  `pagina_web = "google.com"`

Comment: Perfecto, eso era. Muchas gracias @FjSevilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por aclarar el comentario que te ha solucionado el problema:

```
ansMX = dns.resolver.query(pagina_web, 'MX')
ansNS = dns.resolver.query(pagina_web, 'NS')
```

Estás pidiendo los registros MX y NS, es decir, estás pidiendo los registros asociados a la dirección dada para **Mail eXchange** y **Name Server**.

El dominio google.com tiene muchos subdominios:

- www para el buscador
- mail para gmail
- aspmx.l para mail exchange (MX)
- maps
- play
- ns1, ns2, ns3, ns4 ... para DNS (NS)

Pero al reducir la búsqueda a www.google.com no vas a obtener información sobre las direcciones usadas para correo o delegación de DNS.

Por tanto, has ir a lo más global, `google.com`

Answer (score 1):

Respondida en [el comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/146437/#comment274580_146437) de @FJSevilla:

> Usa la versión non-www:
>
> ```
> pagina_web = "google.com"
> ```

---

La respuesta que obtenía (`dns.resolver.NoAnswer`) no era un error en el código, sino que era la respuesta correcta: `www.google.com` no tiene registros NS o MX.

En cambio, `google.com` sí tiene registros NS y MX, y así pude obtener la respuesta.

Comment: Hola Alvaro. Para que la respuesta no parezca el comentario que fue, es mejor explicar por qué quitando las `www` funciona. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: No se como responderle a esa pregunta debido a que no se cual es la diferencia entre la versión www y la no-www. Yo he respondido así debido a que la solución me ha servido.

Comment: Ya pero piensa que las respuestas no solo tienen que servirte a ti si no a futuros users. Ahora que ya sabes la respuesta puedes investigar por qué es asi o buscar en la documentacion qué espera `resolver.query`. Un saludo